# `qemu-mips-static` chroot causing `Invalid ELF image` error

Tags: firmware, linux, mips, qemu, firmware-analysis

I'm trying to emulate a MIPS binary on my Ubuntu 16.04 x86 system, but I'm not able to. I `chroot` into the `squashfs-root` filesystem that I got from `binwalk`ing the firmware image.

```
kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ ls -l
total 3092
drwxr-xr-x 2 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 dev
drwxr-xr-x 5 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 etc
drwxr-xr-x 3 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kan3k1 kan3k1      11 Mar 18  2018 linuxrc -> bin/busybox
drwxr-xr-x 2 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 proc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kan3k1 kan3k1 3120160 Dec 17 01:07 qemu-mips-static
drwxr-xr-x 2 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 2 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 sys
drwxr-xr-x 4 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 usr
drwxr-xr-x 2 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 var
drwxr-xr-x 9 kan3k1 kan3k1    4096 Mar 18  2018 web

kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ sudo chroot . ./qemu-mips-static ./bin/ls
./bin/ls: Invalid ELF image for this architecture

kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ sudo chroot . ./qemu-mips-static ./bin/busybox 
./bin/busybox: Invalid ELF image for this architecture

kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ file bin/ls
bin/ls: symbolic link to busybox
kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ file bin/busybox 
bin/busybox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, stripped

kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ rabin2 -I ./bin/ls
arch     mips
baddr    0x400000
binsz    260852
bintype  elf
bits     32
canary   false
class    ELF32
crypto   false
endian   little
havecode true
intrp    /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
laddr    0x0
lang     c
linenum  false
lsyms    false
machine  MIPS R3000
maxopsz  16
minopsz  1
nx       false
os       linux
pcalign  0
pic      false
relocs   false
relro    no
rpath    NONE
sanitiz  false
static   false
stripped true
subsys   linux
va       true

kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ rabin2 -I ./bin/busybox 
arch     mips
baddr    0x400000
binsz    260852
bintype  elf
bits     32
canary   false
class    ELF32
crypto   false
endian   little
havecode true
intrp    /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
laddr    0x0
lang     c
linenum  false
lsyms    false
machine  MIPS R3000
maxopsz  16
minopsz  1
nx       false
os       linux
pcalign  0
pic      false
relocs   false
relro    no
rpath    NONE
sanitiz  false
static   false
stripped true
subsys   linux
va       true
```

My system info:

```
kan3k1@kaido:~/firmware/_firmware.bin.extracted/squashfs-root$ uname -a
Linux kaido 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 10:19:08 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? All the resources that I was able to find online have something to do with `.so` files causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your binaries are little-endian, so you neeed qemu-mips**el**.

Comment: Got it! `sudo chroot . ./qemu-mipsel-static bin/ls` worked. Thanks!